# AppEngine Nodejs not redirecting HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, yaml

I have set up my `app.yaml` file like so:

```
runtime: nodejs10
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
  # Serve all static files with urls ending with a file extension
  - url: /(.*\..+)$
    static_files: dist/\1
    upload: dist/(.*\..+)$
    # catch all handler to index.html
  - url: /.*
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/index.html
```

This has worked for Flask projects, but with my Nodejs project it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to change `script: auto` to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `secure: always` to each [handler that this behavior](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref?hl=en#handlers_secure) is desired. Please notice that you have two handlers wit the same `- url: /.*`. The last definition of that url does not have the `secure` argument.